# Error when including FontAwesome in an Icon using react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, expo

Having to work with an application that someone else developed and not available anymore. Pretty new to React-Native and Expo. Keep on getting this error:

```
fontFamily 'FontAwesome' is not a system font and has not been loaded through Expo.Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Expo.Font.loadAsync.
```

I googled this and got some other links about what people were encountering and how they solved it e.g.

- import {Font} from 'expo' and async load it in via componentDidMount
- import {FontAwesome} from '@expo/vector-icons' package
- tried deleting where it was used and refreshing app

Here is an example of an Icon a previous developer returned:

`<Icon name="sign-in" color={'#FFFFFF'} type="font-awesome" />;`

which is being imported like this from `react-native-elements`:

`import { Icon, Button } from 'react-native-elements'`

All of these ways I tried didn't work. Tried reading up on Custom Font loading but it looks like everything is being done right to me in the repo. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to load in font-awesome.

Make sure and run `rnpm link` after you yarn or npm install the module.

#### Using

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = (<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />)
```